# Random process with stationary independent increments determined by first order distribution?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

It says in my random processes book that if a random process $X_t$ with stationary independent increments has value $0$ at the start ($X_0 = 0$) then it is completely determined by it's first order distribution.

And that $E(X_t) = at$ where $a = E(X_1)$. From this it makes sense to me that

$$
X_t = tX_1 
$$

But I don't know how to make it a formal proof, I tried for natural numbers,

$$
X_t = (X_t - X_{t/2} ) + (X_{t/2} - X_0) = 2X_{t/2}
$$

And similarly for arbitrary $n\in \mathbb{N}$,

$$
X_t = nX_{t/n}
$$

I don't know how to extend this to real numbers, i tried like this, if $n \to \infty$, then $nt$ "converges" (I know this cannot work, this is where I am stuck) to a natural number and so

$$
X_t = ntX_{1/n}
$$

Then because $nX_{1/n} = X_1$, it follows that $X_t = tX_1$

How would one really prove this, i.e. extend the natural numbers argument to real numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the equality

$$X_t = 2 X_{t/2}$$

does **not** hold. It follows from stationarity of the increments that

$$X_{t}-X_{t/2} \stackrel{d}{\sim} X_{t/2},$$

i.e. they are equal in distribution and not almost surely. (Recall that $X \stackrel{d}{\sim}Y$ does not imply $X+Y = 2X$.) This means that we can use the equation

$$X_t = \underbrace{(X_t-X_{t/2})}_{\sim X_{t/2}} + (X_{t/2}-X_0) \tag{1}$$

whenever we want to draw conclusions about the distribution of $X_t$. E.g. $(1)$ implies

$$\mathbb{E}X_t = \mathbb{E}(X_t-X_{t/2}) + \mathbb{E}(X_{t/2}) = 2 \mathbb{E}(X_{t/2}).$$

---

One of the most basic examples for processes with stationary and independent increments is the Poisson process. Just draw a picture how the typical sample path of a Poisson process looks like - then you will see that $X_t = t X_1$ does not hold.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't understand the difference between equality in distribution and almost sure equality. But still, how would one expand your argument for $$\mathbb{E}X_t = \mathbb{E}(X_t-X_{t/2}) + \mathbb{E}(X_{t/2}) = 2 \mathbb{E}(X_{t/2}).$$ To real numbers (replace 2 with arbitrary real number).

Comment: @vladimirm First step: Show that $\mathbb{E}X_t = t \mathbb{E}X_1$ holds for any $t \in \mathbb{Q}_+$. To this end, show that $$\mathbb{E}X_n = n \mathbb{E}X_1 \qquad \mathbb{E}X_{1/m} = \frac{1}{m} \mathbb{E}X_1.$$ Second step: Use that $t \mapsto \mathbb{E}X_t$ is continuous in order to conclude $\mathbb{E}X_t = t \mathbb{E}X_1$ for all $t \geq 0$.

Comment: I have shown that it holds for every $t \in \mathbb{Q}_+$, now $\mathbb{E}X_t$ is continuous because of: $$\lim_{\Delta t \in \mathbb{Q}  \to 0} \mathbb{E}X_{t+\Delta t} - \mathbb{E}X_t = \lim_{\Delta t \in \mathbb{Q}  \to 0}\Delta t \mathbb{E}X_1 = 0$$ But how does that prove it for every real number, continuity is show above only for the rationals?

Comment: @vladimirm No, this doesn't show the continuity of $t \mapsto \mathbb{E}X_t$. You have to prove that $$\lim_{\Delta t \in \mathbb{R} \to 0} \mathbb{E}X_{t+\Delta t} - \mathbb{E}X_t = 0$$ for any $t \geq 0$. (If you have further questions on this stuff, it might be a good idea to open a new question.)